# What does 'yellow highlight' on '.then' mean in jest coverage report?

Tags: vue.js, testing, jestjs, frontend, vue-test-utils

I'm testing vue project with vue-test-utils.

When I saw its coverage report, [image: test coverage report where yellow lines are highlighted on .then]

I found the yellow highlight on '.then()' like above.

I knew that 'yellow highlight' in jest coverage report means 'branch is not covered', so I thought that '.catch() case must not be covered!'

but when I ran test,
[image: test result]

it seems that '.then' case and '.catch' case are all going through the test!(since console shows both 'error' for '.catch' case and 'run' for '.then' case.

So I wanna know that is there any misunderstanding to the concept of yellow highlighting on .then... and what it exactly means!

Comment: It could highlight wrong line if there are problems with source maps. That you mix then and async/await doesn't make it easier and probably can be fixed by switching to async/await.

Comment: @EstusFlask Thank you for your comment! Do you mean that I should change the 'then/catch' expression to 'async/await'?

Comment: Yes. Not sure if this will help but should make things more straightforward